# Recover a board from corrosion damages

Tags: repair, corrosion

A smart device board shown various issues and stopped to power on. I have opened it to determine the cause of the problem and I have seen it has multiple corrosion signs.

[image]

The board wasn't exposed to water or humidity by myself, and it is an item produced around a year ago, I'm surprised to see it in such conditions, probably these damages have been caused by some problem in the production or distribution chain.

In what way I could recover it from corrosion damages?

Comment: Is that corrosion or just dust and debris? Hard to tell. Most of the metal parts don't look corroded. Fiberglass PCB material doesn't really corrode. I would try cleaning it with canned air first and see how it looks.

Comment: With NO POWER APPLIED you can clean with pure water (distilled or deionised or tap water if drinkable) and a good stiff brush. IPA is useful but water is an amazingly effective polar solvent. Then dry very very very thouroughly before applying power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circuit boards can often be cleaned with Isopropyl Alcohol (also referred to as Isopropanol or IPA, easily purchasable from most online vendors or a local pharmacy in the first aid section).  I use a tooth brush for gently scrubbing corrosion off of PCB surfaces and allowing the board to dry *completely* before trying to power it on again. That said, the damage looks fairly severe and it's unclear whether cleaning alone will recover the board's normal functions.

Example: [https://www.amazon.com/Swan-M314-Isopropyl-Alcohol-99/dp/B00NMPLSZ6/ref=sr_1_12?keywords=Isopropanol&qid=1573709322&sr=8-12](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NMPLSZ6)

Comment: I use this technique to recover digital intercom circuit boards that apartment managers damage accidentally. They are pressure washing the lobby area and manage to get a good squirt of detergent water into the intercom panel. The IPA method works well.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is It possible to use ethanol instead?

Comment: Save the ethanol for internal use, although high-impedance circuits *might* benefit from an alcohol bath. Check your board for a back-up battery or super-capacitor that might have residual voltage before washing. Liquid can trap underneath components - a forced air blowdry might be a good idea if you're impatient.